# using a ListBox In WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I've never done any work in wpf before and i'm supposed to add an undo button. I want it to look like what the undo button in VS looks like (click to undo once, hover over to get the more in depth listbox). I managed to get whats in the picture. It is inside a menuitem and i can't figure out how to just make it a white box without any borders or anything. Please Help!
Here's code:

```
 <MenuItem Header="Edit" Width="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" >
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuCopy" Header="Copy to Excel" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="copy.ico" Width="24" Height="24"  />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuUndo" Header="Undo Last Action" IsEnabled="true">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Undo.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="Item" Height="10" Width="100">

                    </ListBoxItem>

                </ListBox>
            </MenuItem>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the whole submenu item to just be a white box?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I was thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try to override the ControlTemplate and set the styles and remove padding, borders.

```
<Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
           ...
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Check this msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx) for Listbox style.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar to wpf at all. Would this go inside the list box or around the list box?

Comment: This is the style of Listbox. You can edit styles and apply it to your control. check the msdn link.